# Complex eigenvectors unique up to rotations, or just $\pm$?

Tags: complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We know that real eigenvectors are unique up to $\pm$ when normalized.

Are complex eigenvectors unique modulo rotation? I noticed I can multiply a complex eigenvector (which was normalized to 1) by $exp(i\cdot\pi\cdot j/2),\qquad j=1,2,3,\ldots$  and that is still an eigenvector of the original $Ax=\lambda x$ problem.

So, this means that the **normalized** complex eigenvectors I get from numerical software can always be rotated? Or am I misinterpreting, and I may only switch the eigenvector's $\pm$ sign, instead  of rotation?

Comment: The $1\times1$ matrix $[7+i]$ has a single complex eigenvalue and it can't be rotated at all, before or after normalization. Either there's an error in your code, an error in your transcription into this question, or you're working with a special family of transformations and your question is missing that context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $Av=\lambda v$, then $A(cv)=\lambda (cv)$ for any scalar $c$. If you allow scalars to be complex, you can therefore multiply with complex numbers like $e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}j}$ and get new eigenvectors. This seems to be what you are doing.

However, this doesn't correspond as nicely to rotations as you perhaps think. If you allow scalars to be complex, then the "line" in the direction $v$ consists of all *complex* multiples of $v$, hence in particular also $e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}j}v$. What you have done is change the base field. You are not doing real linear algebra anymore, but complex linear algebra.

The idea that multiplying with a norm one complex number corresponds to a rotation only really works if you work in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, i.e. if you're doing two-dimensional real linear algebra.

Comment: right, i had the feeling i was breaking something in doing that, even though it seemed to work. Thanks!